# how to create an function thats returns an array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c++11

I would like to know how to prototype a function that returns a array which also takes in an array. after prototyping the array how can i implement it

is this correct?

```
coffee* getData(*coffe);

int main() {
    coffee cf[256];
    coffee FinalCoffee[256];
    FinalCoffee=getData(cf);
}

coffee getData(coffee objcf[]) {
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
        objcf[i].brand="nescafe";
    }
    return coffee;
}
```

Plsease do advice me on this. i need to be able to get back array so that i can pass the updated array to another function to process it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn’t even have matching declaration and function definition. This doesn’t work.

But the following does:

```
std::vector<coffee> getData(std::vector<coffee> const& objs) {
    std::vector<coffee> result;
    // Do something to fill result
    return result;
}
```

But if, as in your example, you want to *manipulate* the original array, rather than returning a new one, then it makes more sense to not have a return value at all, and to pass the argument as a non-const reference:

```
void manipulateData(std::vector<coffee>& objs) {
    for (auto& obj : objs)
        obj.brand = "nescafe";
}
```

As a rule of thumb, try to avoid C arrays in favour of C++ standard library containers. This will make your life much, *much* easier.

Comment: In the example given, the OP appeared to want to manipulate the array, one wonders if he actually needs to return a new one at all, but in fact modify the original.

Comment: how to do be de protoyting and implementation for vectors in the earlier situtation

Comment: @rasul1719435 The prototype is *identical* to the function header. Nothing to change.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph void manipulateData(std::vector<coffee>& objs); \\This will be the prototype is it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in C++.  References to the rescue.  Ugly syntax ahead, typedefs are recommended:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<size_t N>
int (&f(int(&A)[N])) [N] {
        for(auto& i: A) i +=10;
        return A; 
} 

int main() {
        int A[3] = {1,2,3};
        auto& AA = f(A);
        for(auto i: AA)   cout << i << "\n";
}
```

But as, Konrad Rudolph noted, you actually do not need return anything from f(),  your array is modified in place.  And your function can be much simpler:
`void f(int (&A)[N])`

Answer (score 2):

To start with, the declaration (prototype) and the definition (implementation) of the function headers are different:

```
coffee* getData(*coffe);
```

Versus

```
coffee getData(coffee objcf[])
```

The last one doesn't even return a pointer.

As for your question, your prototype says that `getData` returns a *pointer* but you assign it to an *array*. This will not work. Instead declare `FinalCoffee` as a pointer:

```
coffee cf[256];
coffee* FinalCoffee;
FinalCoffee=getData(cf);
```

However you don't really need that. When `getData` modifies the array you pass as argument, then those modifications will be in the `cf` array too as arrays are passed as references.

Comment: so can i type like this

     void getData(*coffee); This is the prototyping
     void getData(coffee cf[] ){

      }

      int main(){
      coffee cf[256];
      getData(cf);
    }

Comment: @rasul1719435 Yes that's correct. But make sure the prototype and the actual implementation matches!

Comment: void getData(*coffee); \\Prototying
void getData(coffee cf[]){}\\implementation

are they correcct

Comment: @rasul1719435 Besides the asterisk being placed wrong in the prototype, the compiler will probably accept it. However it may be confusing to see the prototype with a pointer argument and the implementation with an array argument.

Comment: so if i use the following way i dont need to return the coffee object right since we are modifing on it direcctly?